# Quest Migration Manager for Exchange, and custom Managed Folders - causing duplicates

Tags: exchange-2010

So, we're doing a big cross-forest Exchange (2010->2010) migration, using Quest. It is not working correctly for mailboxes that have custom Managed Folders, which my client uses instead of retention policies.

Quest will bring over the "Managed Folders" hierarchy to the target mailbox, but not as system managed folders - easy to confirm in OWA, the system ones have a little green-n-white badge on them. Exchange also creates an empty "Managed Folders" hierarchy, so the user has two sets of folders named "Managed Folders" - one with all their content, but no retention policy so it all gets expired, and one with no content, but the correct policy.

Not awesome. We're working with Quest tech support right now, but they're leaning towards "not our problem" currently. Any ideas?

We have already tried this : removed the MF Mailbox policy from a target mailbox entirely (confirming by showing that there are no longer any "Managed Folders" at all), and then do another sync. User now has a "Managed Folders" hierarchy. Apply the MF Mailbox policy. Exchange creates an empty "Managed Folders1" hierarchy. Same problem, slightly different flavor.

/Edit to clarify - this only happens if we do the Quest Sync-n-Switch method. If we process the mailbox using the RUC (Resource Update) method, the Managed Folders are not duplicated.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a lot of fun.  Best I can muster up would be your 2nd paragraph followed by a "move the folder contents from the old to the newly created one with the correct policy".  You could look into something like [this Powershell script](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/emeamsgdev/archive/2012/04/27/powershell-script-to-move-items-from-one-folder-to-another-in-a-user-s-mailbox.aspx) that you'd need to re-write but may allow you to script the moving of the items from the old folders to the new.

Other than that...I've got nothing.

Comment: Yup - don't want to have to get into the level of detail of doing something like IT delving into users' mailboxes, even with a script. Plus, the target mailbox's folder that contains the items, but not the correct policy, is vulnerable to cleanup if the Managed Folder assistant runs before a move-script can finish. Not an ideal situation